# Agregar sentencias de insert para ejecutarlas juntas (vb.net >> informix)

Tags: sql, vb.net, insert, informix

Necesito saber si puedo agregar sentencias de inserts para ejecutarlas juntas.

Me explico:

Tengo esta sentencia en string:
`sql="insert into linea values (id_linea, id_insp_linea, id_daño)`

siendo las ids los datos que brinda el usuario, para una linea de una inspección, inspección que puede llevar `N`lineas.

Lo que quiero saber es si puedo guardar el string de ese `sql`con los datos en cierto punto, para utilizar de nuevo la `sql`con nuevos datos `N`veces, para luego hacer todos los insert juntos?

Digamos en pasos

1. `sql="insert into linea values (1, 1, 3)` almacenar para ejecutar
   luego
2. `sql="insert into linea values (2, 1, 6)` almacenar para ejecutar luego
3. `sql="insert into linea values (3, 1, 1)` almacenar para ejecutar luego
4. `sql="insert into linea values (4, 1, 2)` almacenar para ejecutar luego
5. ejecuto los insert todos juntos.

Estoy utilizando vb.net y la bd es informix (decisión del profesorado)

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informix permite encadenar consultas de inserción, pero eso no sería lo más eficiente.

Podrías hacer lo que dices, separando cada consulta con `;`:

`sql = "INSERT INTO linea VALUES (1, 1, 3); INSERT INTO linea VALUES (2, 1, 6);INSERT INTO linea VALUES (3, 1, 1); INSERT INTO linea VALUES (4, 1, 2);"`

Pero lo más eficiente sería hacer un único `INSERT` con varios conjuntos de valores, separados por `,`:

`sql = "INSERT INTO linea VALUES (1, 1, 3), (2, 1, 6), (3, 1, 1), (4, 1, 2);"`

Suponiendo que estás trabajando en WindowsForms, podría ser algo así:

```
Public Class MiForm
    Dim _listaValores As List(Of Integer())

    Private Sub MiForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'vaciamos la lista
        _listaValores.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub AgregarConjunto(a As Integer, b As Integer, c As Integer)
        'agregamos un conjunto de 3 valores a la lista
        _listaValores.Add({a, b, c})
    End Sub

    Private Sub GenerarSQL()
        'definimos dos plantillas
        Dim _plantillaINSERT As String = "INSERT INTO linea VALUES {0};" 'plantilla para todo el INSERT
        Dim _plantillaVALUES As String = "({0}, {1}, {2})" 'plantilla para cada trío de valores

        If _listaValores.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox("No hay valores para insertar")
        Else
            'pasamos la lista de valores a una lista de strings usando la plantilla
            Dim _listaValores2 As New List(Of String)
            For Each i As Integer() In _listaValores
                'cada string queda algo como (1, 2, 3)
                _listaValores2.Add(String.Format(_plantillaVALUES, i(0), i(1), i(2)))
            Next i

            'hacemos un string combinando los elementos de la lista, separándolos con una coma
            'quedaría algo como (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)
            Dim arrayConComas As String = Strings.Join(_listaValores2.ToArray, ",")
            'metemos esos valores en la plantilla principal
            'quedaría algo como INSERT INTO linea VALUES (1,2,3), (4,5,6);
            Dim sql As String = String.Format(_plantillaINSERT, arrayConComas)

            MsgBox("La consulta final sería: " & sql)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

En el click de algún botón: `AgregarConjunto(valor1, valor2, valor3)` para agregarlo a la lista.

Por último, en el click de algún otro botón: `GenerarSQL()`

El código podría ser mucho más breve, pero preferí hacerlo paso a paso, explicando, para que fuera más claro.

Comment: si, pero a lo que voy es que las lineas que lleva cada una 3 datos son indeterminadas, en un caso pueden ser 2 lineas, en otro 15 lineas, en otro 5, digamos que sin límite, esos datos son 3 campos de un formulario vb.net, puedo guardar los valores de esos 3 campos, limpiar el formulario añadir los  3 datos de nuevo sin pisar los primeros 3? y al momento de terminar tirar el insert juntos como me dijiste sin importar las cantidad de lineas.

Comment: digamos que pueda llamar el sql y asignarle los valores, de manera dinámica sin perder los datos que ingresó el usuario en el paso anterior,para limpiar el formulario e ingresar nuevos datos.

Comment: claro, mi respuesta muestra que sí se pueden ejecutar varios insert en un único paso, y lo otro sería cuestión de la lógica de tu programa. A grandes rasgos y suponiendo que estés usando WinForms, deberías crear una variable global a nivel del formulario, ir llenándolo con valores, y en el momento de insertar recorrer esa variable generando el string para insertar. ... ahora edito la respuesta con algo de código VBNET para que tengas una guía

Comment: @Vizz3rdriX ya agregué el código VBNET

Comment: muchisimas gracias, lo voy a estudiar paso a paso!